# Program for mass-managing audio cards

Tags: audio, ubuntu, audio-recording

I am looking to do simultaneous translation of a conference we are hosting.  I would prefer to have the mixing for this project on computer; ideally Ubuntu, as that is what I am the most familiar with.  Basically, the software must be able to:

1. Input from one audio card (wired to speaker's mic)
2. Record from that input
3. Output that input to an output on the same card (earphones for me)*
4. Input from a second audio card (microphone for me)
5. Output to the second audio card (to a mixer attached to the earphones of those who are having the simultaneous translation done)

What are my options?  Is there such a program on Ubuntu?

<sub>* This would be optional, since I could split the signal to 1. the computer for recording and 2. my earphones</sub>

Comment: This is not good.  I just got the Tumbleweed Badge on a Question with a Bounty.  ;)

Comment: Why 2 different audio cards? This decreases your possibilities a lot

Comment: @user2875404, because I don't have an audio card that supports 2 inputs.